# i can't run a linear regression and cross validation. can someone enlighten me? i get errors such as could not convert string to float

Tags: python, cross-validation

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib as mpl        
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
from statsmodels.formula.api import ols 
import statsmodels.api as sm        
import scipy        
import scipy.stats      
import seaborn as sns       
import numpy.random as npr      
import math     
from scipy.stats import norm        
import sqlite3 as sql       
import seaborn      
from numba import jit, prange       
        
df = pd.read_csv('ODI-2021.edited.csv')
df.info()
sr_targets = pd.Series(df['What is your stress level (0-100)?'])
sr_targets.describe()
df_features = df.drop('What is your stress level (0-100)?', axis=1)
print (df_features)
df_features.describe()

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm

df.isnull().sum()
df_missing = df.dropna()
df_missing.shape

X = df["What is your stress level (0-100)?"]
y = df["Time you went to be Yesterday"]
est = sm.OLS(y, X.astype(float)).fit()
model = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)

-ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'over 9000'

model.summary()

-AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'

from sklearn import preprocessing

def convert(df):
    number = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
    data['Date'] = number.fit_transform(df['Date'])
    data=data.fillna(-999)
    return data

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
result = model.fit(df_features, sr_targets)

-ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3/16/2021'

sr_coef = pd.Series(result.coef_, index=df_features.columns)
sr_coef

-NameError: name 'result' is not defined

sr_endog = sr_targets.copy()
df_exog = sm.add_constant(df_features)

model = sm.OLS(sr_endog, df_exog)
result = model.fit()

-ValueError: Pandas data cast to numpy dtype of object. Check input data with 
 np.asarray(data)

result.summary()

-NameError: name 'result' is not defined

cross validation

from sklearn.linear_model import LassoCV
from sklearn.model_selection import Fold
nb_folds = 10
cv = KFold(n_splits=nb_folds)
model = LassoCV(fit_intercept=True, cv=cv, n_alphas=200, max_iter=2000)
result = model.fit(df_features_rescaled, sr_targets)

-NameError: name 'df_features_rescaled' is not defined

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[16,15])

xvalues = np.log10(result.alphas_)
rmse_path = np.sqrt(result.mse_path_)
for k in range (nb_folds):
    yvalues = rmse_path[:,k]
    plt.plot(xvalues, yvalues)
    pos_ymin = yvalues.argmin()
    plt.plot(xvalues[pos_ymin], yvalues[pos_ymin], marker='o')

plt.axvline(np.log10(result.alpha_))
plt.title('RMSE for differebt alpha', fontsize=20)
plt.grid()

-NameError: name 'result' is not define

sr_coef = pd.Series(result.coef_, index=df_features.columns)
sr_coef
```

this is my code and these are the errors im getting, could someone help me with what im doing wrong? i have looked up the errors and i have no clue how to fix those. my data set has numbers but also dates and answers such as yes no and university level  education level responses which i have no clue how to convert in float. i have been trying to run a regression with two columns which consist of numbers and i get there errors. for the cross validation i am dropping one column and im using the rest and im getting the error that i havent defined the variable result which i have , im clueless

3.thanks in advance!

Comment: Please reduce this to a [mre] and show the exact error message including full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Each of your errors means something. Learning to read the errors is extremely important in understanding what is going on. For example,

```
est         = sm.OLS(y, X.astype(float)).fit()
model       = sm.OLS(y, X).fit()
predictions = model.predict(X)

-ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'over 9000'
```

This appears to suggest that someone place the phrase "over 9000" in the cell of the CSV file you are opening. Hence, python is having trouble figuring out how to convert that to a float. Same thing would happen if you tried to run

```
float("over 9000")
```

It appears the data needs to be cleaned up a bit before it can be used by your sm. It appears that python is trying to tell you the same thing here too:

```
-ValueError: could not convert string to float: '3/16/2021'
```

The string "3/16/2021" has symbols that are not apart of a float(), namely "/" symbol.

I think it would be helpful if you broke up your errors and concerns into separate questions, then people could tackle them one at a time for you.